# Access/Excel VBA Failing

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have an Access database that runs a macro that opens some Excel files and formats the sheets to prepare them for later use. This code has been running fine until my company applied the latest Office Updates, and now I am getting a compile error "Method or data member not found" and its happening on the line...

```
wDate = Mid(XlSheet.Range("B4").Value, 13, Len(XlSheet.Range("B4").Value))
```

singling out the "Range". I cannot figure out why this started happening. Thanks for any assistance. Full code below...

```
Function ExcelProcess()
'Variables to refer to Excel and Objects
Dim MySheetPath As String
Dim Xl As Excel.Application
Dim XlBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim XlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim MyFile As Variant
Dim MySheet As Variant
Dim wBook As Variant
Dim wSheet As Variant
Dim wDate As Variant

Dim rng As Range
Dim cel As Range


MyFile = Array("w1.xlsx", "w2.xlsx", "w3.xlsx")
MySheet = Array("T2_IND", "APPR_IND", "SLG_APPR_IND", "SLG_IND", "C2A_IND", "C3_IND", "C4_IND", "T3_IND", "T4_IND", "C2B_IND")

For Each wBook In MyFile
    ' Tell it location of actual Excel file
    MySheetPath = "\\fs1\Training\CSC_Training_Ops\Training Only\Buzzard\Pulled Data\" & wBook

    'Open Excel and the workbook
    Set XlBook = GetObject(MySheetPath)

    'Make sure excel is visible on the screen
    XlBook.Windows(1).Visible = True

    For Each wSheet In MySheet
        'Define the sheet in the Workbook as XlSheet
        Set XlSheet = XlBook.Worksheets(wSheet)
        wDate = Mid(XlSheet.Range("B4").Value, 13, Len(XlSheet.Range("B4").Value))

        XlSheet.Range("A15").FormulaR1C1 = "WE_Date"
        If XlSheet.Range("A16").Value <> "No data found" Then
            Set rng = XlSheet.Range(XlSheet.Range("A16"), XlSheet.Range("A16").End(xlDown).Offset(-1))

            For Each cel In rng.Cells
                With cel
                    .FormulaR1C1 = wDate
                    .NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
                End With
            Next cel
        End If
        XlSheet.Rows("1:14").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        XlSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Next
    XlBook.Close SaveChanges:=True
Next

'Clean up and end with worksheet visible on the screen
Set Xl = Nothing
Set XlBook = Nothing
Set XlSheet = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: You have all appropriate references added as well?

Comment: @adidashawn6: yes, the reference in Access (Tools ... References) probably needs to be updated to refer to the updated version of Office

Comment: Are you 100% sure the hard-coded sheet names exist *exactly as-is* in the workbook you're opening? If the sheet names look legit, look for leading or trailing spaces. If that array has the names of every sheet in the workbook, consider iterating the worksheets with a `For Each` loop, rather than pulling them by hard-coded name from the `Worksheets` collection.

Comment: Thanks  Our Man in Bananas and QHarr. It was the Microsoft Office 16 Object Library. Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I tested that theory, that scenario would case a 'Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range:' error.

Comment: @AdamVincent right - I got kind of side-tracked into improving other aspects of the code :)

Comment: @adidashawn6 you can mark a helpful answer as "accepted" by clicking the hollow checkmark next to the voting buttons at the top-left of that answer. That gives the answerer +15, gives you +2, and takes your question off the "unanswered" list. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any apparent problems with the code itself.

Since this broke with when you updated the office, I would venture a guess that it is an issue with the reference.

1. Go to Tools->References->
2. Remove all references to Excel Object Library
3. Save & Close the Macro Worksheet (Shouldn't be necessary, but only takes a sec)
4. Re-Open
5. Add in reference to only the latest version of Microsoft Excel 1X.0 Object Library

If this does not solve the issue, you may have to run a repair on office

1. Control Panel -> Add Remove Programs
2. Locate Microsoft Excel (Or office suite)
3. Run Repair

Finally, it was suggested to try late binding. Remove the references to the `Microsoft Excel Object Library` and update your declarations to:

```
Dim Xl As Object
Dim XlBook As Object
Dim XlSheet As Object
Set Xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If `wSheet` is a `Chart` sheet's name, then you'll be getting a *type mismatch* error for trying to assign a `Chart` to a `Workbook` local variable, rather than getting an *index out of bounds* for trying to find a chart sheet in the worksheets collection. `XlSheet` would have to be declared `As Chart` for it to work, and then the rest of the code would make no sense whatsoever, since you can't call `.Range` on a `Chart` sheet. No, clearly the OP *means* to work with a `Worksheet`, thus using the `Worksheets` collection is perfectly appropriate. The bottom part of your answer makes no sense.

Comment: Have an upvote - I don't see what else could be wrong here. Caveat: AFAIK you don't get to pick which version you early-bind to. If "resetting" references doesn't help, then the only solution could be to late-bind the Excel type library calls (i.e. outright remove the reference and replace all Excel types with `Object` in declarations, and any used Excel constant/enum by their underlying integer value.

Comment: Switching to late-references is often a good way to go. If you have a DEV and PROD version of the database, you can also use conditional compilation to use early binding on your development machine (so you get Intellisense, etc.), and use late binding on your production version, so you don't run into version issues.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you got upgraded from Office 14.0 to 15.0 or 16.0?  Hit Alt+F11 > Tools References and look for errors in the window that opens.  Search for the correct reference and click it.  As others have suggested, consider rewriting the code using some late binding methodologies.